# How do I identify the server correctly when importing a CSV to a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am writing a program to import a CSV file into a SQL Server database, but I'm not sure where you enter the SQL Server name for when this connects. I had found some code that helps prep my CSV for importing, but I'm looking for some guidance on how to correctly set this up. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 with C#.

```
static void InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy(System.Data.DataTable csvFileData)
{
    using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ProductHost;Initial Catalog=yourDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
    {
        dbConnection.Open();

        using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection))
        {
                s.DestinationTableName = "TestTable";

                foreach (var column in csvFileData.Columns)
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());

                s.WriteToServer(csvFileData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "having trouble writing how to connect to the actual server" mean? Does the code you provided not connect? Error messages?

Comment: @Caius Jard, I'm not sure where you need to add the SQL Server name when using this section of code. I'll update my question as well.

Comment: This is confusing.  The SQL Server name follows right after "Data Source" in that connection string... What are you asking about, if not that?

Comment: Hey @Amy, I'm sorry for the confusion on this. A lot of this code I got from another post, but I'm trying to update the correct fields in this. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL server name (the ip or host name of the server) goes in the connection string, where you've written "ProductHost"

If your server runs multiple instances of sqlserver and they're named instances then you put the instance name in separated from the host name by a backlash eg "ProductHost\sqlexpress"

A tip for creating connection strings:

- Create a file called `a.udl`
- double click it and edit the relevant parameters to get a successful connection
- open the file in a text editor - it contains a valid connection string

Be aware that the choice of Provider will affect the format of the connection string - your computer probably has several providers capable of connecting to sql server; choose the .Net one

Comment: Thank you! I will test this out and let you know. I really appreciate the assist.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `ProductHost` would be the SQL Server instance name or Server IP Address (if on the default port).